# Los state en vuejs que han cambiado de valor se pierden al refrescar el navegador?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy investigando un poco sobre vuejs para el desarrollo de unos proyectos, tengo una duda con el login, estoy usando unos state en el store para guardar algunos datos, pero al refrescar el navegador, sus valores que ya han sido modificados vuelven a su valor inicial. Adjunto algunas imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al refrescar el navegador queda así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como lo dije soy nuevo en vues, y más aún en vuex; lo que deseaba era consumir los datos del usuario actualizados que obtuve al autenticar al usuario; colocarlos en un componente header.vue. al inicio se muestran los datos, pero el problema es justamente cuando actualizado el navegador, estaba pensando tmb guardar esos datos en el localStorage; pero no se si será una buena práctica.

Comment: entiendo, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuex no persiste el estado al refrescar la pagina.

Vuex es un estado, que si lo vemos de otra forma, no son mas que variables globales que viven solo en la instacia de la aplicación.

El problema, es que al refrescar, estamos generando una nueva instancia, y por lo tanto esos valores son volatiles.

Para persistir entre instancias de nuestra aplicación esos valores, se puede usar el metodo que uno guste (cookie, localstorage o cualquier otro valido).